# Data filter with jquery that changes opacity

Tags: jquery, css, filtering

I'm building a site with filterable projects. I'm basically wanting to change the opacity of elements within the filtered class. So 100% opacity elements that have the 'active' class, and 50% opacity for everything else that doesn't have the 'active' class. On click each element should fade up or down. Here's the code. I'm scratching my head with this one...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#filters li a').click(function() {
    // fetch the class of the clicked item
    var ourClass = $(this).attr('class');

    // reset the active class on all the buttons
    $('#filters li').removeClass('active');
    // update the active state on our clicked button
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

    if(ourClass == 'all') {
      // show all our items
      $('#projects').children('li.two').show();
    }
    else {
      // 50% Opacity of all elements that don't share ourClass
      $('#projects').children('li:not(.' + ourClass + ')').fadeTo('slow', 0.5, function();
      // !00% Opacity of all elements that do share ourClass
      $('#projects').children('li.' + ourClass).fadeTo('slow', 1, function();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: so what is the problem you facing up??

Comment: I realise this is not cross-browser, but you could consider just using toggleClass(), and using a -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease; opacity: 0.5 ... also consider using hasClass('all') instead of attr('class')

Comment: Basically I can get this to work as a show and hide. But What i want to do is keep all elements in place and just fade down to 50% if they dont have 'active' class and fade up to 100% if they do. Make sense?

Comment: Ok. Got this sorted. Used .animate instead of show to fake the toggle.

Comment: Will post answer when i'm allowed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#filters li a').click(function() {
// fetch the class of the clicked item
var ourClass = $(this).attr('class');

// reset the active class on all the buttons
$('#filters li').removeClass('active');
// update the active state on our clicked button
$(this).parent().addClass('active');

if(ourClass == 'all') {
  // show all our items
  $('#projects').children('li.two').animate({opacity:1}, 400);
}
else {
  // hide all elements that don't share ourClass
  $('#projects').children('li:not(.' + ourClass + ')').animate({opacity:0.15}, 400);
  // show all elements that do share ourClass
  $('#projects').children('li.' + ourClass).animate({opacity:1}, 400);
}
return false;
});`
```